# SP2013: Form ideas for picking multiple non-consecutive dates

Tags: 2013, date-time, list-form

Hi:
I have a "building access request" list on which an employee requests access to our building for the months ahead. One requirement is to allow users to enter multiple dates, even non-consecutive dates and for any given month, on which they intend to access an office building. I am not in favor of adding 31 date pickers. 
 Their **requested** date selections will be matched against their **actual** building access. 
I need ideas for how to construct the multiple dates entry fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to use a multiline text field to store the repeating data as JSON. Embed JavaScript on the form to represent the date picker controls and store the information in the hidden text field.

[Here's an example with generic repeating fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594724/workaround-to-add-repetitive-controls-to-a-sharepoint-form-without-infopath/41623314#41623314); you'd have to do some extra work to replace the simple controls with datepickers.

However, you'll still have the headache of trying to parse that information in order to later compare it against dates from some other database. Depending on how you plan to accomplish that, this approach might not be worth the effort.